# Tracking progress on terminal 1 and showing it in terminal 2

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I'm running ubuntu and i'd like to find a way to track echos from one terminal, and display them in a second terminal. Here is the structure I'm looking to code. The reason for this is I do not want the user to see the first terminal as it downloadds and the echo will quickly be lost. So basically, terminal 1 would be the thing running, showing what's it's doing (for advanced users) and terminal 2 would be showing predetermined echos that's linked to terminal 1

Comment: The question is not clear, you want to share the terminal screen to someone else?

Comment: Again, I don't think your question has anything to do with Vim at all.

Comment: @balki let's say I have these commands in a shell script : 

echo "we will now download java6"
sudo apt-get install java6.
(right here, all the progress would be displayed. Eg : reading package lists....)

I'd like to have ANOTHER SEPERAATE terminal, to ONLY display my echo that I have provided in the first script and NOTHING else. I don't want it to display all the echo that I have provided in the script at once, but it'll follow the progress of the first terminal.

Comment: @romainl right. I keep forgetting. I'm writing these codes in Vim.

Comment: @JunyuTeoh What about `echo "whatever you want"; sudo apt-get install java6 2>&1 >> /tmp/logfile`? That will save the output of `apt-get` in case you need to review it later, but not display it on the screen...

Comment: @twalberg that's actually a better solution! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to use a file in the middle.

From your first process, you would redirect the output to a file

```
script.sh > foo
```

And from another terminal, you keep reading what is written in the file to see the actual output of the script

```
tail -f foo
```

You probably don't want to do that for hours though

That being said, are you sure this is really what you want to do? 
Woudln't it be better to have some kind of [debug levels](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html), so that you can activate/deactivate the type of messages to be shown ?

Comment: As of right now, this is what I want to do. I just got into this a few hours ago and I'm just creating a little script to basically set up ubuntu to build android. Perhaps somewhere a long the road I'll find a better solution to this. 

Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem. If you want people to help you faster for your next questions, try to follow the rules :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry! I will keep that in mind next time. Thank you again!